# Auto-updating line of business iOS apps via intune

Tags: ios, ipa, auto, intune

I am struggling to find out whether it is possible to push line of business iOS app updates out to users/devices via Microsoft Intune. I'd be grateful to hear if anyone else encountered the scenario or found a way to resolve.

My scenario is:

- As a large organisation of 25000+ users, we have developed many in-house mobile applications that are not suitable for distribution via the Apple Public Store or the VPP Program. These are signed with an in-house Apple certificate and distributed via line of business apps option in Intune.
- It is not suitable for all line of business apps to be marked as "required" (which forces the app to be downloaded to the device).
- Certain mobile apps may receive updates where it is necessary that all users make use of the latest version.

The question is - is it possible to release an update to an iOS line of business app, and push the update out to users who have the app already installed?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It has been a number of years since I looked at this (I have changed roles now) but when I did it wasn't possible to push updates to apps that were not marked as "required". :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to speak to a contact at Microsoft who gave me the following information.

This shows conditions in which an LOB iOS app update will automatically update even when it was installed with the available intent:

[Add an iOS/iPadOS line-of-business app to Microsoft Intune | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/lob-apps-ios#step-5-update-a-line-of-business-app)

For an iOS LOB app targeted with available intent, auto-update of the application will happen as long as the following conditions are met:

- The end user must request the specific Intune app from the Company Portal and the app must be successfully installed, or the app is already installed on the device.
- The targeting for the user has not changed (app assignment with available intent is not removed and user is not removed from the group membership in the life cycle of the app assignment).
- If the previous version of the app is installed through required intent, then the available app update will not happen. The app will be updated automatically as long as the user/device is part of required intent group.
- If the app has both available and required deployments targeted, the resolved intent becomes 'RequiredAndAvailable'. Note: You cannot create Available and Required deployments to the same AAD Group, but you can use different AAD group with same members in it. If the app was installed automatically on devices after the Required deployment is created (not manually installed from Company Portal) and the required deployment is later removed, the Available app update won't happen automatically on those devices and the users have to request the app from Company Portal.

I have an LOB app to update in the coming weeks, so I will try the above and report back in the hope it works and helps others.